# Why are DateTime.Now DateTime.UtcNow so slow/expensive

Tags: c#, performance, micro-optimization

I realize this is way too far into the micro-optimization area, but I am curious to understand why Calls to DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow are so "expensive". I have a sample program that runs a couple of scenarios of doing some "work" (adding to a counter) and attempts to do this for 1 second. I have several approached of making it do the work for a limited quantity of time. The examples show that DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow are significantly slower than Environment.TickCount, but even that is slow compared to just letting a separate thread sleep for 1 second and then setting a value to indicate the worker thread to stop.

So my questions are these:

- I know that UtcNow is faster because it does not have time zone information, why is it still so much slower than TickCount?
- Why is reading a boolean faster than an int?
- What is the ideal way of dealing with these types of scenarios where you need to allow something to run for a limited amount of time, but you do not want to waste more time checking the time than actually doing the work?

Please pardon the verbosity of the example:

```
class Program
{
    private static volatile bool done = false;
    private static volatile int doneInt = 0;
    private static UInt64 doneLong = 0;

    private static ManualResetEvent readyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodA_PrecalcEndTime();
        MethodB_CalcEndTimeEachTime();
        MethodC_PrecalcEndTimeUsingUtcNow();

        MethodD_EnvironmentTickCount();

        MethodX_SeperateThreadBool();
        MethodY_SeperateThreadInt();
        MethodZ_SeperateThreadLong();

        Console.WriteLine("Done...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void MethodA_PrecalcEndTime()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        var doneTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
        var startDT = DateTime.Now;
        while (DateTime.Now <= doneTime)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        var endDT = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: {0,30} Total Counted: {1,20}", endDT.Subtract(startDT), cnt);
    }

    private static void MethodB_CalcEndTimeEachTime()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        var startDT = DateTime.Now;
        while (DateTime.Now <= startDT.AddSeconds(1))
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        var endDT = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: {0,30} Total Counted: {1,20}", endDT.Subtract(startDT), cnt);
    }

    private static void MethodC_PrecalcEndTimeUsingUtcNow()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        var doneTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(1);
        var startDT = DateTime.Now;
        while (DateTime.UtcNow <= doneTime)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        var endDT = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: {0,30} Total Counted: {1,20}", endDT.Subtract(startDT), cnt);
    }


    private static void MethodD_EnvironmentTickCount()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        int doneTick = Environment.TickCount + 1000; // <-- should be sane near where the counter clocks...
        var startDT = DateTime.Now;
        while (Environment.TickCount <= doneTick)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        var endDT = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: {0,30} Total Counted: {1,20}", endDT.Subtract(startDT), cnt);
    }

    private static void MethodX_SeperateThreadBool()
    {
        readyEvent.Reset();
        Thread counter = new Thread(CountBool);
        Thread waiter = new Thread(WaitBool);
        counter.Start();
        waiter.Start();
        waiter.Join();
        counter.Join();
    }

    private static void CountBool()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        readyEvent.WaitOne();
        var startDT = DateTime.Now;
        while (!done)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        var endDT = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: {0,30} Total Counted: {1,20}", endDT.Subtract(startDT), cnt);
    }

    private static void WaitBool()
    {
        readyEvent.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        done = true;
    }

    private static void MethodY_SeperateThreadInt()
    {
        readyEvent.Reset();
        Thread counter = new Thread(CountInt);
        Thread waiter = new Thread(WaitInt);
        counter.Start();
        waiter.Start();
        waiter.Join();
        counter.Join();
    }

    private static void CountInt()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        readyEvent.WaitOne();
        var startDT = DateTime.Now;
        while (doneInt<1)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        var endDT = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: {0,30} Total Counted: {1,20}", endDT.Subtract(startDT), cnt);
    }

    private static void WaitInt()
    {
        readyEvent.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        doneInt = 1;
    }

    private static void MethodZ_SeperateThreadLong()
    {
        readyEvent.Reset();
        Thread counter = new Thread(CountLong);
        Thread waiter = new Thread(WaitLong);
        counter.Start();
        waiter.Start();
        waiter.Join();
        counter.Join();
    }

    private static void CountLong()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        readyEvent.WaitOne();
        var startDT = DateTime.Now;
        while (doneLong < 1)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        var endDT = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: {0,30} Total Counted: {1,20}", endDT.Subtract(startDT), cnt);
    }

    private static void WaitLong()
    {
        readyEvent.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        doneLong = 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`TickCount` just reads a constantly increasing counter. It's just about the simplest thing you can do.

`DateTime.UtcNow` needs to query the system time - and don't forget that while `TickCount` is blissfully ignorant of things like the user changing the clock, or NTP, `UtcNow` has to take this into account.

Now you've expressed a performance concern - but in the examples you've given, all you're doing is incrementing a counter. I would expect that in your *real* code, you'll be doing rather more work than that. If you're doing a *significant* amount of work, that's likely to dwarf the time taken by `UtcNow`. Before doing anything else, you should measure that to find out whether you're actually trying to solve a problem which doesn't exist.

If you *do* need to improve things, then:

- You can use a timer rather than creating a new thread explicitly. There are various kinds of timers in the framework, and without knowing your exact situation, I can't advise on which would be most sensible to use - but it feels like a better solution than starting a thread.
- You can measure a few iterations of your task, then guess how many will actually be required. You might want to then execute half that many iterations, take stock of how long that's taken, then adjust the number of remaining cycles accordingly. Of course, this doesn't work if the time take per iteration can vary wildly.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will look into timers. I realize the "work" in my example is non-realistic. I was however curious as to where the big impact was coming from.

Comment: @My Other Me: Basically, compared with the work of incrementing a counter, almost *any* work is going to count as a big impact :)

Answer (score 23):

FWIW here is some code that NLog uses to get the timestamp for each log message.  In this case, the "work" is the actual retrieval of the current time (granted, it happens in the context of probably a much more expensive bit of "work", the logging of a message).  NLog minimizes the cost of getting the current time by only getting the "real" time (via `DateTime.Now`) if the current tick count is different than the previous tick count.  This does not really apply directly to your question, but it is an interesting way to "speed up" current time retrieval.

```
internal class CurrentTimeGetter    
{        
  private static int lastTicks = -1;        
  private static DateTime lastDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;        

  /// <summary>        
  /// Gets the current time in an optimized fashion.        
  /// </summary>        
  /// <value>Current time.</value>        

  public static DateTime Now        
  {            
    get            
    {                
      int tickCount = Environment.TickCount;                
      if (tickCount == lastTicks)                
      {                    
        return lastDateTime;                
      }                
      DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;                
      lastTicks = tickCount;                
      lastDateTime = dt;                
      return dt;            
    }        
  }    
}

// It would be used like this:
DateTime timeToLog = CurrentTimeGetter.Now;
```

In the context of your question, you could probably "improve" the performance of your time looping code like this:

```
private static void MethodA_PrecalcEndTime()
{
  int cnt = 0;
  var doneTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
  var startDT = CurrentTimeGetter.Now;
  while (CurrentTimeGetter.Now <= doneTime)                            
  {           
    cnt++;
  }
  var endDT = DateTime.Now;
  Console.WriteLine("Time Taken: {0,30} Total Counted: {1,20}", endDT.Subtract(startDT), cnt);                        }                             
}
```

If `CurrentTimeGetter.Now` is called so frequently that the returned time would be the same many times in a row, only the cost of `Environment.TickCount` must be paid.  I can't say if it really helps with performance of NLog logging such that you would notice or not.

I don't know that it really helps on your question, or if you even need any help anymore, but I thought that it would serve as an interesting example of leveraging a faster operation (`Environment.Ticks`) to potentially speed up a relatively slow operation (`DateTime.Now`) in some circumstances.

Comment: according to my tests, function provided is 3.5 times as slow as simply querying DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: a better approach would be to only get the time once; then start a timer. Every time you want to know the time, you just add the current timer to the old timestamp.

Comment: @ArsenZahray its because is use the `DateTime.Now` that is slow, change it in code with `DateTime.UtcNow` and test it again. - Can take even more improvements for thread safe and less accurate return to make it even faster

Answer (score 14):

For an up-to-date look on the profiled speed of `DateTime.UtcNow` / `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`, see this [dotnet thread](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/25728), where `BenchmarkDotNet` was used to profile.

There was unfortunately a perf regression with the jump to .NET (Core) 3 compared to 2.2, but even reporting with the regressed value, `DateTime.UtcNow` is coming in at a pretty rocking time of `71 ns` (it had been `25 ns`), i.e. 71 billionths of a second.

To put that in perspective, even at the slower speed of `71ns`, it means:

You can call `DateTime.UtcNow` ~ 14,000 times for a cost of only 1 millisecond!

At the previously faster time of `25 ns` (hopefully they will get this performance back), you can call `DateTime.UtcNow` ~ 40,000 times for a cost of 1 millisecond.

I'm not looking at old .NET Framework times here, but at least with the newer bits, I think it can safely be stated that it is at least no longer accurate to say that `DateTime.UtcNow` is "slow/expensive" (I appreciate that the question was asked however!).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, `DateTime.UtcNow` (not to be confused with `DateTime.Now`, which is much slower) is the fastest way you can get time.
In fact, caching it the way @wageoghe proposes decreases performance signifficantly (in my tests, that were 3.5 times).

In ILSpy, UtcNow looks like this:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static DateTime UtcNow
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries"), SecuritySafeCritical]
    get
    {
        long systemTimeAsFileTime = DateTime.GetSystemTimeAsFileTime();
        return new DateTime((ulong)(systemTimeAsFileTime + 504911232000000000L | 4611686018427387904L));
    }
}
```

I think, this suggests that the function is inlined by the compiler to achieve maximum speed. There might be faster ways to get time, but so far, I haven't seen one