# Check if timer elapsed in thread

Tags: c#, .net, events, timer

I have a while loop running in my .NET backgroundworker. I would like to end the loop when Timers.Timer reaches 0.

Problem is that since I'm working in another thread (backgroundworker), my timer has to be instantiated in that same thread. So I can't set any private boolean timer_Elapsed. Nether do I know how to give reference of boolean thro event.

**Code Example:**

```
private bool timer_Elapsed = false;

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Set_Timer(timer);

        timer.Start();

        while(timer_Elapsed) //Has to be a boolean that indicates if timer elapsed
        {
            this.Do_Proces();
        }
    }

    private void Set_Timer(System.Timers.Timer timer)
    {
        timer.Interval = 200;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_ElapsedEvent);
    }

    private void timer_ElapsedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer_Elapsed = true; //I can't set my private boolean since it got instantiated in another thread
    }
```

Particular questions in code. I'm new with this kind of stuff.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want the Do_Proces() to run for 200 milliseconds, when that time passed, I want it to stop. When it stops after 200 millisec, I want to and update GUI with data generated in backgroundWorker. Then check if user wants the proces to stop, if not, I want it to run again.. I use the timer because the thread will have to get restarted to much, this will have effect on the main thread as well, effecting the user experience badly.

Comment: Have you verified that you really can't read/write the private boolean across threads?  I suspect that you can.  Give your current code a try, and update your question to verify that you actually caught an exception.  Otherwise there's no real issue to solve :)

Comment: Fun side-note: if your loop appears like it's not running; it's because your "while" clause should probably be "while(!timer_elapsed)"

Comment: The code is confusing: Do you want that `this.Do_Proces` is called after a specific amount of time (interval)? Since `timer_Elapsed` is initialized with false, the while loop will instantly break and `this.Do_Proces` is never called. What if you use `Thread.Sleep(130); this.Do_Proces();` instead of a Timer at all?

Comment: Ty for comments, sorry for inconvenience. Clarification of whole proces in edit.

Comment: You certainly can set a private field from another thread, however it is likely that you would need to declare `timer_Elapsed` as `volatile`, but @ceykooo's answer is much better if all you need to do is loop until some time interval has expired.

Comment: I know there are ways to set a values from another thread. But my knowledge of threads is to simple. Ty for comments :)

Comment: Just for future reference, if you have a thread that needs to run for 200ms every once in a while (ie, dependent on user input, so maybe once every few seconds), you shouldn't incur any (significant) thread penalty if you use the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx). It keeps reusing a bunch of threads rather than paying the cost of creating a new one each time you want to run something in a separate thread.

Comment: Despite that the solution of ceykooo is better, maybe I have a useful info why your code didn't work. I tried it and after changing `while(timer_Elapsed)` to `while(!timer_Elapsed)` everything worked like you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the timer serving any other purpose other than listed here? If not, you may just want to record the current time at the beginning of your BackgroundWorker method, and change the condition on the while loop to check if the required amount of time has elapsed.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    DateTime start_time = DateTime.Now;

    while(DateTime.Now - start_time < timeout)
    {
        this.Do_Proces();
    }
}
```

Comment: The timer is indeed not serving any other purpose. What does the TimeSpan exactly do? I did quick search on the internet, but don't really understand the concept. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @user1933169 `TimeSpan` is just a class that stores the difference between two `DateTime`s. Basically, TimeSpan is "5 minutes", while DateTime is "Jan 1, 2013 8:13 PM". You can use `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(130)` to match the interval in your original code.

Comment: Ok, got it. Did know concept of DateTime. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a small thing to note. `DateTime.Now` is relatively expensive in terms of time (pun not intended) and cpu usage. I'm sure it shouldn't be an issue in this case, but do be careful when grabbing `DateTime.Now` repeatedly in quick succession on anything performance critical. [Here's some info for ya if you're interested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075525/why-are-datetime-now-datetime-utcnow-so-slow-expensive)

Comment: @IchabodClay I actually didn't know about this, thanks. I don't think I've ever had to use exactly this pattern in production before, but I'll be sure to keep it in mind. Having a method call that takes sufficiently long, or maybe a `Thread.Sleep` in the while loop should be enough to mitigate it.